# why do I get so many duplicates while adding items with a for loop in my list?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and this might be obvious but I'm stuck...So I'm having two lists, alphabet and wordssplit. I'm trying to make a new list (discards) that contains the words from "wordssplit", but only the ones that contain the specific characters from the "alphabet" list. I tried a "for" loop that appends those words in the new list but I'm getting the same words a lot of times. Any ideas?

```
lowercase = text.lower()
wordssplit = lowercase.split()
alphabet = ["a",  "b", "z",  "h"]
discards = []
for x in wordssplit:
    if x not in discards:
        for p in alphabet:
            if p in x:
                discards.append(x)
    print(discards, end='')

txt("could you please show me the code")
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
['please']
['please', 'show']
['please', 'show']
['please', 'show', 'the']
['please', 'show', 'the']
```

Comment: You append the word to `discards` once for *each* letter from `alphabet` that is present in it.  You should `break` from the inner loop after appending.

Comment: What is `txt`? If that's the name of the function you're defining, you should include `def txt(text):` in the code snippet.

Comment: You're not getting the same word multiple times. You're just printing the list every time through the loop, so you see the same thing each time. Take it out of the loop and only print at the end.

Comment: You can also do this with a list comprehension: `discards = [word for word in wordssplit if any(letter in word for letter in alphabet)]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [ask] and [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You need to do a preliminary debugging before asking. 'jasonharper' is wrong and Barmar is right.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, thanks for taking the time to help me!

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you very much, I broke the loop and it works

Comment: @relent95 Good to be here! thank you for the tips